# Non-recursively enumerable set with non-recursively enumerabale complement.

Tags: logic, algorithms

Is it possible to construct a non-recursively enumerable subset of $\mathbb{N}$, such that it's complement is also not recursively enumerable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - indeed, most sets have this property.

---

The simplest (and most broadly applicable) way to see this is just by counting.

Remember, there are **uncountably many** sets of natural numbers (by Cantor's argument), but there are only **countably many** r.e. sets of natural numbers (since there are only countably many Turing machines). This immediately tells us that not every set of natural numbers is r.e., and with a bit of thought (this is a good exercise) also shows that there are sets of natural numbers which are neither r.e. nor co-r.e. *(HINT: otherwise, can you see how to get a "$2$-to-$1$" map from $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ to $\mathbb{N}$, and why this is impossible?)*.

---

We can also do a more computability-flavored argument. Let $A$ be r.e. but not recursive, and consider $$A\oplus (\mathbb{N}\setminus A)=\{2n: n\in A\}\cup\{2n+1: n\not\in A\}.$$ If $A\oplus(\mathbb{N}\setminus A)$ were r.e., then its "odd part" $\{2n+1: n\not\in A\}$ would be r.e., but then $A$ would be both r.e. and co-r.e. and hence recursive; and if $A\oplus (\mathbb{N}\setminus A)$ were co-r.e., then its "even part" $\{2n: n\in A\}$ would be co-r.e., but then $A$ would be both r.e. and co-r.e. and hence recursive *(checking this is a good exercise)*.

---

This, however, still has a drawback: the resulting set $A\oplus (\mathbb{N}\setminus A)$ is still "almost r.e." in the sense that it is [**Turing equivalent**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_degree) to an r.e. set (namely, $A$ itself). A more satisfying computability-theoretic argument uses the [**Turing jump**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_jump): namely, since ${\bf 0}^{''}>_T{\bf 0}^{'}$ and every r.e. set is $\le_T{\bf 0}^{'}$, we know that ${\bf 0}^{''}$ can't be Turing equivalent to any r.e. set. *(And remember that r.e. and co-r.e. are the same up to Turing equivalence.)*